# Require/Use npm module in elixir

Tags: laravel, npm, gulp, webpack, laravel-elixir

i'm tring use es2015 with elixir (first time) and I have a problem with jquery validator:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validate is not a function(…)`.

**My code:**

[image]

I try use `require('jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate')` but also don't work.

what am I doing wrong?